# python urllib.request.urlopen recursion fail

Tags: python, recursion, urllib, web-crawler, urlopen

so i have the code

```
def constructGraph(self,url,doit=5):
    if doit!=0:
        m = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        print('test')
        self.constructGraph('http://example.com',doit-1)
```

but then when I run it, it only runs the first `m = urllib.request.urlopen(url)` and only prints test once even though it supposed to do it twice...

and when i run the debugger, it wouldn’t even go to the print('test') line on the second recursion and would just exit

what did i do wrong?

i'm using python 3

Comment: I don't immediately see anything wrong with your code. Could you post more of your class definition, or maybe what your initial call to constructGraph looks like?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with it. Instead of `'test'`, try printing the values of `doit` and `m`, and maybe dig into `m`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can only have one request open at a time. Try putting a print statement before the urlopen call.